# Erro ao selecionar text de select

Tags: jquery, select

Boa noite, pessoal. Eu tenho um select que lista as cidades do respectivo estado. 
Estou usando esse código pra selecionar uma cidade da lista:

```
$('#txtCidades option').removeAttr('selected').filter("[text=São Lourenço da Mata]").attr('selected', "selected").change();
```

Quando o texto é feito por mais de uma palavra, eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [text=São Lourenço da Mata]

Mas quando a cidade é composta por apenas uma palavra, ele seleciona normalmente sem erro.

Alguém dá uma luz?

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML para completar a pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim:

```
$('#txtCidades option').removeAttr('selected').filter("[text='São Lourenço da Mata']").attr('selected', "selected").change();
```

Comment: Obrigado, uristona. Funcionou perfeitamente. O jogo das aspas duplas e simples.

Answer (score 0):

Quando usas `[text=São Lourenço da Mata]` isso implica que tenhas no HTML um elemento/`option` com esse atributo. [É assim que o jQuery lê a tua query.](https://jsfiddle.net/n3dt5xko/) Algo como

```
<option text="São Lourenço da Mata">foo</option>
```

imagino que não seja esse o caso mas sim queres filtrar o `textContent` dessa option. Nesse caso sugiro usares uma função no método do jQuery.

```
$('ul li').removeAttr('selected').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'São Lourenço da Mata'; 
 }).attr('selected', "selected");
```

Comment: O código é esse aqui:

    `$('#txtCidades option').removeAttr('selected').filter("[text='" + Cidade + "']").attr('selected', "selected").change();`

já com a auteração orientada pelo uristona.

Cidade, nesse contexto, é uma var que recebe uma string proveniente de uma busca de CEP que retorna a cidade.
Sendo assim, eu seleciono o item no select que tem o mesmo texto de Cidade. 
Obrigado pela resposta! E como você e o uristona mostrou, era erro na sítese do meu código.
Obrigado!

Comment: @AbelAndré eu queria ver o HTML desse select. É importante juntares isso na pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Olá, @Sergio, o HTML

```html
<select id="txtUF">
    <option value="">Selecione o estado</option>
    <option value="1">AC</option>
    <option value="2">AL</option>
...
    <option value="24">SC</option>
    <option value="26">SP</option>
    <option value="25">SE</option>
    <option value="27">TO</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="txtCidades">
    <option>Selecione um estado para listar as cidades</option>
</select>
```

Tenho um WebMethod (c#) que carrega listagem das cidades de acordo com a UF selecionada.
Até ai tudo bem. Mas implementei também a busca dos dados do cadastro, sendo assim, necessitava também setar o option do select "txtCidades" com a cidade do cadastro retornado.

O problema consistia nisso: O WebMethod localizava os dados cadastrais corrretos, mas eu tinha descuidado da síntaxe do jQuery pra atribuir ao option do select o texto retornado pela consulta.

o jQuery correto:

```
`$('#txtCidades option').removeAttr('selected').filter("[text='" + Cidade + "']").attr('selected', "selected").change();`
```